# Probability question - horse racing

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The probability of a certain horse finishing in the top 5 of a race is 20%. The probability of him finishing in the top 10 is 45%.

A. What is the probability of him finishing anywhere from 6-10th?
B. What is the probability of the horse finishing anywhere from 6-10th given that he finished in the top 10?

Got some comments saying to post what I have tried so far so I will do that. For part B here is what I tried -
Let P(T5) and P(T10) be the probability of finishing top 5 and top 10.
We know P(T5 and T10) = .2
We also know P(T5 and T10)= P(10) * P(T5|T10)
So .2 = .45 * P(T5|T10)
Then P(T5|T10) = .2/.45
Therefore the probability of finishing anywhere from 6-10th given that finished in top 10 is 1-P(T5|T10)= 1-.2/.45

If there is not enough information to answer - what other info do we need?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: If finishing in the top 10 includes finishing 10th you do not have enough information to answer.  Can you see why?  What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you [edit] the question to show us what you have tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help. Just "do this for me" is not a good way to ask here.

Comment: I think you might be interested in [How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) from our [Help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that the question is "probability to finish in the top $[6;10]$

Thus the probability is

A. $45\%-20\%=25\%$

B. $\frac{25}{45}=\frac{5}{9}\approx 55.56\%$

@Jack: the lack of information is that you do not know the probability to arrive exactly 10th. In any case the results will not be very far from the ones I showed you.

---

Edit: further explanation on B.

Set the events:

A: your horse arrives in the interval $[6;10]$

B: your horse arrives in the top 10, say in the interval $[1;10]$

The question is to calculate

$$\mathbb{P}[A|B]=\frac{\mathbb{P}[A \cap B]}{\mathbb{P}[B]}=\frac{\mathbb{P}[A]}{\mathbb{P}[B]}=\frac{0.25}{0.45}$$

It is self evident that $\mathbb{P}[A \cap B]=\mathbb{P}[A]$ as $A\subset B$

Comment: Got it - I changed the question to reflect this. So to clarify this is now the answer to the edited question right?

Comment: @JackSitt : that is my humble opinion.

Comment: Thanks how did you know to do 25/45 for part B? I posted a potential solution in the edits but my way would obviously takes a lot longer.

Comment: @JackSitt :  I just applied the definition of conditional probability. See the edit in my answer